# Searching for certain patterns and pulling out data

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

area shape="rect" coords="348,140,362,152" alt="Driving for 0h30, starting 05-25 11:34.
at 4 mi WSW of Pleasant Prairie, WI" title="Driving for 0h30, starting 05-25 11:34.
at 4 mi WSW of Pleasant Prairie, WI"

I am looking for a way to pull the first word or 2 out of alt,could be driving or off duty , etc. and pull the date time it started, how long it lasted as well as the location city and state. having trouble with the regex to pull each part of data

Comment: What `regex`es have you tried thus far?

Comment: [/alt=](.+?)[/,] but its not quiet pulling what i want

Comment: Is the text always in that general format? i.e. if `alt` is **off duty**, is that all the text there is there, or is there still the starting time, location, etc? Or is the text that's in there somewhat freeform?

Comment: the duty status changes from off duty, driving, on duty, sleeper birth, the duration will always be listed. and the location will always be listed as well

Comment: Provided an example for one of the components in an answer that you should be able to use to determine how to apply them to the other components, also.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do this, especially depending on exactly how you want to get the data out of the `regex` and how the data being scanned by the `regex` can vary, but, for the **alt** portion, you might try something like this:

```
alt=\"(Driving|(?:(?:off|on) duty)|sleeper birth) for (.+)?, starting (.+)?\. at (.+)? title
```

With `case insensitivity` turned on.

And then the various `group`s (1-4 here) contain the components.

You can do similar things for the other components, either in a separate regex for each component (that may be easier to read), or as one large regex, which just adds additional `group`s as it goes for each component.

You can use this site to help test the regex as you continue to work it: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html